# Blurred background-image on Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've just started developing my first Bootstrap powered design but I'm struggling on how to create a blurred background-image.

Here's my code:

```css
  body {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;

  }

  body::before{
  background: url(/scnet/includes/images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  }
```

```html
 <body>
 <div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputUser" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip on second input!" name="secondname" required autofocus>
  <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Memorable Data</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputMem" class="form-control" placeholder="Memorable Data" required>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Password Reset</button>
      </form>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[type=text][id=inputEmail]').tooltip({ /*or use any other selector, class, ID*/
     placement: "right",
     trigger: "focus"
    });
   </script>
    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="includes/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Currently nothing happens (background stays white) - I know the image reference is correct because I tried add it to `body` class and it loaded fine.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

body::before {
  background: url(/scnet/includes/images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: That just just a 40px height image line across the top of the screen and pushes down the login box, should have explained more that it's a responsive background that covers the whole screen so displaying as a block and adding a height makes the `-webkit-background-size: cover;` redundant.

Comment: See my edited answer. I'm assuming you have a particular reason for wanting the background image on the ::before pseudo element instead of the `body`.

Comment: Thanks, I made some edits to that code and got it working, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap, there's a whole variety of ways to approach this (including @Garret's recommendation above.)  Without knowing all of your custom CSS (if any) it's hard to know exactly what you're after, but for an alternative, have a look at this code snippet on [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/91532).